# Server response to polymer property values

Tags: google-apps-script, polymer-1.0

```
<dom-module id="payment-list">
    <template>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{clients}}">
    <paper-item>
       <span>{{item.Name}}</span>
             &nbsp;|&nbsp;
       <span>{{item.Amount}}</span>
    </paper-item>
    </template>
    </template>
      <script>
        Polymer({
          is: 'payment-list',
          properties: {
            clients: {
                notify:true,
                type: Array,
                value: [{Name:'A', Amount:'100'}, 
                        {Name:'B', Amount:'200'}]        
            }
          },
          handleComplete: function(NewValues){
          /***********/alert(NewValues);/***********/
          },
          ready: function(){
              google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(this.handleComplete).GS_GetClients();
          }
        });
      </script>
    </dom-module>
```

I am using google.script.run to communicate with GAS function GS_GetClients(). GS_GetClients will be returning an object and I am trying to bind this new values to the property 'clients'.
When I do the alert I see that new values are passed to the handleComplete function from the server side GAS function. But I am not able assign the new values to the property 'clients'.

I cant set the values by using this.clients = NewValues. This is making the value to undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The call to google.script.run is asynchronous.

The result seems to return, when the rendering of {{clients}} has already happend.

So in your success handler handleComplete(..) you somehow have to tell Polymer to redraw.

I do not know Polymer but from the docs [Polymer data binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#set-path) it seems as if you can do it like this :

```
Polymer({
  ...
  setClients: function(clients) {
    this.clients = clients;
    // Notification required for binding to update!
    this.notifyPath('clients', this.clients);
  }
});
```

How to call custom methods in Polymer is explained here [member-functions](http://www.sitepoint.com/access-member-functions-polymer-elements/) , sorry can not provide a more detailed answer regarding Polymer.

Comment: But how do I assign 'NewValues' to 'clients'. Property 'clients' is not accessible inside handleComplete function. If I give to log 'clients' inside 'handleComplete' it gives result as undefined.